# PHP FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL does not work correctly

Tags: php, email-validation, filter-var

I'm using PHP 5.3.10. This is the code:

```
<?php
$email = "test@example.c";
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        echo "Email: ".$email." correct";
else
        echo "email not correct";
?>
```

It returns: `"Email: test@example.c` correct.

I think that a top level domain with only one character is not correct (I'm not aware of one-character-length TLD according to this list: `http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt`).

So, `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` filter is working correctly or not?

Comment: The first part before the @ cannot be longer than 64 characters... In my case this caused a few hours of debugging, but `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` had right...

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Validating e-mail adresses is kinda complicated.
Take a look at this list:

Valid email addresses

1. niceandsimple@example.com
2. very.common@example.com
3. a.little.lengthy.but.fine@dept.example.com
4. disposable.style.email.with+symbol@example.com
5. user@[IPv6:2001:db8:1ff::a0b:dbd0]
6. "much.more unusual"@example.com
7. "very.unusual.@.unusual.com"@example.com
8. "very.(),:;<>[]".VERY."very@\
   "very".unusual"@strange.example.com
9. postbox@com (top-level domains are valid hostnames)
10. admin@mailserver1 (local domain name with no TLD)
11. !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}|~@example.org
12. "()<>[]:,;@\"!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}| ~.a"@example.org
13. " "@example.org (space between the quotes)
14. üñîçøðé@example.com (Unicode characters in local part)

Invalid email addresses

1. Abc.example.com (an @ character must separate the local and domain
   parts)
2. A@b@c@example.com (only one @ is allowed outside quotation marks)
3. a"b(c)d,e:f;gi[j\k]l@example.com (none of the special characters
   in this local part are allowed outside quotation marks)
4. just"not"right@example.com (quoted strings must be dot separated, or
   the only element making up the local-part)
5. this is"not\allowed@example.com (spaces, quotes, and backslashes may
   only exist when within quoted strings and preceded by a backslash)
6. this\ still"not\allowed@example.com (even if escaped (preceded by
   a backslash), spaces, quotes, and backslashes must still be
   contained by quotes)

Source http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Allmost all e-mail validation implementations are "bugged" but the php implementation is fine to work with because it accepts all common e-mail adresses

UPDATE:

Found on http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Regarding "partial" addresses with no . in the domain part, a comment in the source code (in ext/filter/logical_filters.c) justifies this rejection thus:

```
 * The regex below is based on a regex by Michael Rushton.
 * However, it is not identical.  I changed it to only consider routeable
 * addresses as valid.  Michael's regex considers a@b a valid address
 * which conflicts with section 2.3.5 of RFC 5321 which states that:
 *
 *   Only resolvable, fully-qualified domain names (FQDNs) are permitted
 *   when domain names are used in SMTP.  In other words, names that can
 *   be resolved to MX RRs or address (i.e., A or AAAA) RRs (as discussed
 *   in Section 5) are permitted, as are CNAME RRs whose targets can be
 *   resolved, in turn, to MX or address RRs.  Local nicknames or
 *   unqualified names MUST NOT be used.
```

And here is a link to the class from Michael Rushton (link broken see source below)
Which supports both RFC 5321/5322

```
<?php
  /**
   * Squiloople Framework
   *
   * LICENSE: Feel free to use and redistribute this code.
   *
   * @author Michael Rushton <michael@squiloople.com>
   * @link http://squiloople.com/
   * @package Squiloople
   * @version 1.0
   * @copyright © 2012 Michael Rushton
   */
  /**
   * Email Address Validator
   *
   * Validate email addresses according to the relevant standards
   */
  final class EmailAddressValidator
  {
    // The RFC 5321 constant
    const RFC_5321 = 5321;
    // The RFC 5322 constant
    const RFC_5322 = 5322;
    /**
     * The email address
     *
     * @access private
     * @var string $_email_address
     */
    private $_email_address;
    /**
     * A quoted string local part is either allowed (true) or not (false)
     *
     * @access private
     * @var boolean $_quoted_string
     */
    private $_quoted_string = FALSE;
    /**
     * An obsolete local part is either allowed (true) or not (false)
     *
     * @access private
     * @var boolean $_obsolete
     */
    private $_obsolete = FALSE;
    /**
     * A basic domain name is either required (true) or not (false)
     *
     * @access private
     * @var boolean $_basic_domain_name
     */
    private $_basic_domain_name = TRUE;
    /**
     * A domain literal domain is either allowed (true) or not (false)
     *
     * @access private
     * @var boolean $_domain_literal
     */
    private $_domain_literal = FALSE;
   /**
     * Comments and folding white spaces are either allowed (true) or not (false)
     *
     * @access private
     * @var boolean $_cfws
     */
    private $_cfws = FALSE;
    /**
     * Set the email address and turn on the relevant standard if required
     *
     * @access public
     * @param string $email_address
     * @param null|integer $standard
     */
    public function __construct($email_address, $standard = NULL)
    {
      // Set the email address
      $this->_email_address = $email_address;
      // Set the relevant standard or throw an exception if an unknown is requested
      switch ($standard)
      {
        // Do nothing if no standard requested
        case NULL:
          break;
        // Otherwise if RFC 5321 requested
        case self::RFC_5321:
          $this->setStandard5321();
          break;
        // Otherwise if RFC 5322 requested
        case self::RFC_5322:
          $this->setStandard5322();
          break;
        // Otherwise throw an exception
        default:
          throw new Exception('Unknown RFC standard for email address validation.');
      }
    }
    /**
     * Call the constructor fluently
     *
     * @access public
     * @static
     * @param string $email_address
     * @param null|integer $standard
     * @return EmailAddressValidator
     */
    public static function setEmailAddress($email_address, $standard = NULL)
    {
      return new self($email_address, $standard);
    }
    /**
     * Validate the email address using a basic standard
     *
     * @access public
     * @return EmailAddressValidator
     */
    public function setStandardBasic()
    {
      // A quoted string local part is not allowed
      $this->_quoted_string = FALSE;
      // An obsolete local part is not allowed
      $this->_obsolete = FALSE;
      // A basic domain name is required
      $this->_basic_domain_name = TRUE;
      // A domain literal domain is not allowed
      $this->_domain_literal = FALSE;
      // Comments and folding white spaces are not allowed
      $this->_cfws = FALSE;
      // Return the EmailAddressValidator object
      return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Validate the email address using RFC 5321
     *
     * @access public
     * @return EmailAddressValidator
     */
    public function setStandard5321()
    {
      // A quoted string local part is allowed
      $this->_quoted_string = TRUE;
      // An obsolete local part is not allowed
      $this->_obsolete = FALSE;
      // Only a basic domain name is not required
      $this->_basic_domain_name = FALSE;
      // A domain literal domain is allowed
      $this->_domain_literal = TRUE;
      // Comments and folding white spaces are not allowed
      $this->_cfws = FALSE;
      // Return the EmailAddressValidator object
      return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Validate the email address using RFC 5322
     *
     * @access public
     * @return EmailAddressValidator
     */
    public function setStandard5322()
    {
      // A quoted string local part is disallowed
      $this->_quoted_string = FALSE;
      // An obsolete local part is allowed
      $this->_obsolete = TRUE;
      // Only a basic domain name is not required
      $this->_basic_domain_name = FALSE;
      // A domain literal domain is allowed
      $this->_domain_literal = TRUE;
      // Comments and folding white spaces are allowed
      $this->_cfws = TRUE;
      // Return the EmailAddressValidator object
      return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Either allow (true) or do not allow (false) a quoted string local part
     *
     * @access public
     * @param boolean $allow
     * @return EmailAddressValidator
     */
    public function setQuotedString($allow = TRUE)
    {
      // Either allow (true) or do not allow (false) a quoted string local part
      $this->_quoted_string = $allow;
      // Return the EmailAddressValidator object
      return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Either allow (true) or do not allow (false) an obsolete local part
     *
     * @access public
     * @param boolean $allow
     * @return EmailAddressValidator
     */
    public function setObsolete($allow = TRUE)
    {
      // Either allow (true) or do not allow (false) an obsolete local part
      $this->_obsolete = $allow;
      // Return the EmailAddressValidator object
      return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Either require (true) or do not require (false) a basic domain name
     *
     * @access public
     * @param boolean $allow
     * @return EmailAddressValidator
     */
    public function setBasicDomainName($allow = TRUE)
    {
      // Either require (true) or do not require (false) a basic domain name
      $this->_basic_domain_name = $allow;
      // Return the EmailAddressValidator object
      return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Either allow (true) or do not allow (false) a domain literal domain
     *
     * @access public
     * @param boolean $allow
     * @return EmailAddressValidator
     */
    public function setDomainLiteral($allow = TRUE)
    {
      // Either allow (true) or do not allow (false) a domain literal domain
      $this->_domain_literal = $allow;
      // Return the EmailAddressValidator object
      return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Either allow (true) or do not allow (false) comments and folding white spaces
     *
     * @access public
     * @param boolean $allow
     * @return EmailAddressValidator
     */
    public function setCFWS($allow = TRUE)
    {
      // Either allow (true) or do not allow (false) comments and folding white spaces
      $this->_cfws = $allow;
      // Return the EmailAddressValidator object
      return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Return the regular expression for a dot atom local part
     *
     * @access private
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getDotAtom()
    {
      return "([!#-'*+\/-9=?^-~-]+)(?>\.(?1))*";
    }
    /**
     * Return the regular expression for a quoted string local part
     *
     * @access private
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getQuotedString()
    {
      return '"(?>[ !#-\[\]-~]|\\\[ -~])*"';
    }
    /**
     * Return the regular expression for an obsolete local part
     *
     * @access private
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getObsolete()
    {
      return '([!#-\'*+\/-9=?^-~-]+|"(?>'
        . $this->_getFWS()
        . '(?>[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-!#-\[\]-\x7F]|\\\[\x00-\xFF]))*'
        . $this->_getFWS()
        . '")(?>'
        . $this->_getCFWS()
        . '\.'
        . $this->_getCFWS()
        . '(?1))*';
    }
    /**
     * Return the regular expression for a domain name domain
     *
     * @access private
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getDomainName()
    {
      // Return the basic domain name format if required
      if ($this->_basic_domain_name)
      {
        return '(?>' . $this->_getDomainNameLengthLimit()
          . '[a-z\d](?>[a-z\d-]*[a-z\d])?'
          . $this->_getCFWS()
          . '\.'
          . $this->_getCFWS()
          . '){1,126}[a-z]{2,6}';
      }
      // Otherwise return the full domain name format
      return $this->_getDomainNameLengthLimit()
        . '([a-z\d](?>[a-z\d-]*[a-z\d])?)(?>'
        . $this->_getCFWS()
        . '\.'
        . $this->_getDomainNameLengthLimit()
        . $this->_getCFWS()
        . '(?2)){0,126}';
    }
    /**
     * Return the regular expression for an IPv6 address
     *
     * @access private
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getIPv6()
    {
      return '([a-f\d]{1,4})(?>:(?3)){7}|(?!(?:.*[a-f\d][:\]]){8,})((?3)(?>:(?3)){0,6})?::(?4)?';
    }
    /**
     * Return the regular expression for an IPv4-mapped IPv6 address
     *
     * @access private
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getIPv4MappedIPv6()
    {
      return '(?3)(?>:(?3)){5}:|(?!(?:.*[a-f\d]:){6,})(?5)?::(?>((?3)(?>:(?3)){0,4}):)?';
    }
    /**
     * Return the regular expression for an IPv4 address
     *
     * @access private
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getIPv4()
    {
      return '(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d{2}|[1-9]?\d)(?>\.(?6)){3}';
    }
    /**
     * Return the regular expression for a domain literal domain
     *
     * @access private
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getDomainLiteral()
    {
      return '\[(?:(?>IPv6:(?>'
        . $this->_getIPv6()
        . '))|(?>(?>IPv6:(?>'
        . $this->_getIPv4MappedIPv6()
        . '))?'
        . $this->_getIPv4()
        . '))\]';
    }
    /**
     * Return either the regular expression for folding white spaces or its backreference
     *
     * @access private
     * @param boolean $define
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getFWS($define = FALSE)
    {
      // Return the backreference if $define is set to FALSE otherwise return the regular expression
      if ($this->_cfws)
      {
        return !$define ? '(?P>fws)' : '(?<fws>(?>(?>(?>\x0D\x0A)?[\t ])+|(?>[\t ]*\x0D\x0A)?[\t ]+)?)';
      }
    }
    /**
     * Return the regular expression for comments
     *
     * @access private
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getComments()
    {
      return '(?<comment>\((?>'
        . $this->_getFWS()
        . '(?>[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\'*-\[\]-\x7F]|\\\[\x00-\x7F]|(?P>comment)))*'
        . $this->_getFWS()
        . '\))';
    }
    /**
     * Return either the regular expression for comments and folding white spaces or its backreference
     *
     * @access private
     * @param boolean $define
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getCFWS($define = FALSE)
    {
      // Return the backreference if $define is set to FALSE
      if ($this->_cfws && !$define)
      {
        return '(?P>cfws)';
      }
      // Otherwise return the regular expression
      if ($this->_cfws)
      {
        return '(?<cfws>(?>(?>(?>'
          . $this->_getFWS(TRUE)
          . $this->_getComments()
          . ')+'
          . $this->_getFWS()
          . ')|'
          . $this->_getFWS()
          . ')?)';
      }
    }
    /**
     * Establish and return the valid format for the local part
     *
     * @access private
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getLocalPart()
    {
      // The local part may be obsolete if allowed
      if ($this->_obsolete)
      {
        return $this->_getObsolete();
      }
      // Otherwise the local part must be either a dot atom or a quoted string if the latter is allowed
      if ($this->_quoted_string)
      {
        return '(?>' . $this->_getDotAtom() . '|' . $this->_getQuotedString() . ')';
      }
      // Otherwise the local part must be a dot atom
      return $this->_getDotAtom();
    }
    /**
     * Establish and return the valid format for the domain
     *
     * @access private
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getDomain()
    {
      // The domain must be either a domain name or a domain literal if the latter is allowed
      if ($this->_domain_literal)
      {
        return '(?>' . $this->_getDomainName() . '|' . $this->_getDomainLiteral() . ')';
      }
      // Otherwise the domain must be a domain name
      return $this->_getDomainName();
    }
    /**
     * Return the email address length limit
     *
     * @access private
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getEmailAddressLengthLimit()
    {
      return '(?!(?>' . $this->_getCFWS() . '"?(?>\\\[ -~]|[^"])"?' . $this->_getCFWS() . '){255,})';
    }
    /**
     * Return the local part length limit
     *
     * @access private
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getLocalPartLengthLimit()
    {
      return '(?!(?>' . $this->_getCFWS() . '"?(?>\\\[ -~]|[^"])"?' . $this->_getCFWS() . '){65,}@)';
    }
    /**
     * Establish and return the domain name length limit
     *
     * @access private
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getDomainNameLengthLimit()
    {
      return '(?!' . $this->_getCFWS() . '[a-z\d-]{64,})';
    }
    /**
     * Check to see if the domain can be resolved to MX RRs
     *
     * @access private
     * @param array $domain
     * @return integer|boolean
     */
    private function _verifyDomain($domain)
    {
      // Return 0 if the domain cannot be resolved to MX RRs
      if (!checkdnsrr(end($domain), 'MX'))
      {
        return 0;
      }
      // Otherwise return true
      return TRUE;
    }
    /**
     * Perform the validation check on the email address's syntax and, if required, call _verifyDomain()
     *
     * @access public
     * @param boolean $verify
     * @return boolean|integer
     */
    public function isValid($verify = FALSE)
    {
      // Return false if the email address has an incorrect syntax
      if (!preg_match(
          '/^'
        . $this->_getEmailAddressLengthLimit()
        . $this->_getLocalPartLengthLimit()
        . $this->_getCFWS()
        . $this->_getLocalPart()
        . $this->_getCFWS()
        . '@'
        . $this->_getCFWS()
        . $this->_getDomain()
        . $this->_getCFWS(TRUE)
        . '$/isD'
        , $this->_email_address
      ))
      {
        return FALSE;
      }
      // Otherwise check to see if the domain can be resolved to MX RRs if required
      if ($verify)
      {
        return $this->_verifyDomain(explode('@', $this->_email_address));
      }
      // Otherwise return 1
      return 1;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes it does, because you can use a local domain name etc.
It's to complicated to validate the TLD and most implementations just accept (even invalid address).

The e-mail validation implementations aren't that strict

Comment: You say: 9. postbox@com (top-level domains are valid hostnames), but the FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL filter on this address returns false! So, does the filter accept as valid only some email addresses (included "joe@example.c") but not others (anyway, valid like "postbox@com")? This is a weird behavior!

Comment: @RosarioRusso: time to file a bug report, because you're right: it does return false, and it shouldn't!

Comment: It's not a bug (i'm guessing here), i think the php implementation is focussed on e-mail adressess used on webpages. So they made it easy for beginners and all web developers. 

But this is just a guess, should be nice to have that information from the php team.

Comment: But i agree with you the php implementation is vague.
Because when it doesn't accept top-level domains or local (The php filter method wants a . somewhere at the domain part). They could validate the TLD on the length.

Comment: @visserSander: `filter_var('"very.(),:;<>[]\".VERY.\"very@\\ \"very\".unusual"@strange.example.com',FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` _is_ accepted, but `postbox@com` is not. I'd call that a bug

Comment: @RosarioRusso: `postbox@com` is definitely not a valid email-address. If you purchase any email hosting package, you have to enter a valid `domain name(example.com)`. And you can send an email address to a user `user1@example.com`, if he is user in that email account. In short, the php implementation is right, because it should check the `domain name` after the `@` sign.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem hmmm i agree

Comment: @aaron: I couldn't disagree more with _everything_ you said: You state that the PHP implementation is right, but the official RFC specs aren't? I mean... really?! Since the update, I can sort of see why `a@b` isn't considered valid, though I can't help to see it as a decision that is, in part at least, motivated by lazyness, too... running in a test environment `mail('root@localhost');` doesn't seem too outlandish, does it?

Comment: @VisserSander: +1 for taking the effort to go through the actual source!

Comment: So, basically just look for the @ symbol and no whitespace. Looks like this should be enough after all, as long as the @ is not inside quotes.

Comment: Actually " "@example.org is a valid email adres

Comment: Does it handle new gTLDs like .technology, .school, .studio, etc? The example #8 valid email address is very long after the @ but still ends in .com so not sure if the check is still for 2-4 characters after the last <dot>

Comment: Yes new longer top levels are supported in PHP. But i noticed that `filter_var` in php7.1 doesn't consider `उपयोगकर्ता@उदाहरण.कॉम`  as valid email address

Comment: FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL doesn't handle international email address.  This format results in false and I email it almost everyday.  {local}@{domain}.co.ke

Answer (score 2):

FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL is not supporting PHP 5.2.14

Comment: I noticed this because it was working locally on my machine, but not when I uploaded my code to the hosting server.

Answer (score 2):

There is a PHP class on google code for validating email addresses:

http://code.google.com/p/php-email-address-validation

You can use it like

```
include('EmailAddressValidator.php');
$validator = new EmailAddressValidator;
if ($validator->check_email_address('test@example.org')) { 
    // Email address is technically valid 
} else {
    // Email not valid
}
```

Comment: Is deprecated ... Stick to PHP's http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php which covers almost all use cases as per RFC 822

Answer (score 0):

`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` can only tell you if the address is formatted correctly.

Consider these examples

```php
// "not an email" is invalid so its false.
php > var_export(filter_var("not an email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
false
// "foo@a.com" looks like an email, so it passes even though its not real.
php > var_export(filter_var("foo@a.com", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
'foo@a.com'
// "foo@gmail.com" passes, gmail is a valid email server,
//  but gmail require more than 3 letters for the address.
var_export(filter_var("foo@gmail.com", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
'foo@gmail.com'
```

So `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` is only good at telling you when it's completely wrong, not when it's right.

You will need to use a service like [Real Email](https://isitarealemail.com) which can do indepth email address validation.

```php
// foo@gmail.com is invalid because gmail require more than 3 letters for the address.
var_export(file_get_contents("https://isitarealemail.com/api/email/validate?email=foo@gmail.com"));
'{"status":"invalid"}'

// foobar@gmail.com is valid
var_export(file_get_contents("https://isitarealemail.com/api/email/validate?email=foobar@gmail.com"));
'{"status":"valid"}'
```

For a more see https://docs.isitarealemail.com/how-to-validate-email-addresses-in-php

Answer (score -2):

I chose to use :

```
<?php
$email =$argv[1];$result= is_valid_email($email); echo $result;
function is_valid_email($email) { return preg_match('/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"\']+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"\']+)*)|("[^"\']+"))@((\[\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\d\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/', $email); }
?>
```

in my forum software
https://github.com/neofutur/MyBestBB/blob/master/include/email.php#L39

but officialy it is : 
http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html
( longer too)