# php mail eregi and preg_match error

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, eregi

I have php mail form for users and after upgrade got this error:

> Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated

Here is code line which is checking email for valid:

```
if(trim($_POST['COTB_05']) == '') {$hasError = true;} else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['COTB_05']))) {$hasError = true;} else {$COTB_05 = trim($_POST['COTB_05']);}
```

Tried to change **eregi** to **preg_match**:

```
if(trim($_POST['COTB_05']) == '') {$hasError = true;} else if (!preg_match("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['COTB_05']))) {$hasError = true;} else {$COTB_05 = trim($_POST['COTB_05']);}
```

but got another error:

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found in W:\domains\localhost\content\email_cotb.php on line 4

**FIX:**
Forgot to use **/i**

```
!preg_match("/^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i"
```

So it's not case sensetive :)

Comment: Enclose your regex with "//"(delimiters)

Comment: There's also `filter_var()` and FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL btw.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220158/php-filter-validate-email-not-works-correctly :(

Comment: Why are you limiting TLDs to 4 characters? See the Iana Root Zone Database: http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db