# Issue with validate email using PHP

Tags: php, email

I have the following code to check if user input is a valid email, there might be a few questions already about this but noone seems to validate the PHP function.

```
/* check if valid email*/
public function isValidEmail($email){
    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If we do a test using this function:

```
isValidEmail('some?=Wrong@mail.com')
```

This should return `false` because characters like `?=` are inside the email address. Is there a stricter way to check email?

Comment: By "to write out nothing" - Do you mean it returns true with the test input?

Comment: You pass the variable to your function as `$epost` but then access it as `$email` - this won't check the passed variable.

Comment: Spelling error, question updated,

Comment: It returns true even tho i have ?= in email adress.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220158/php-filter-validate-email-does-not-work-correctly your test address seems in fact valid.

Comment: all the more reasons I never liked that filter/function, and they said I was *"the crazy boy who cried wolf"*

Comment: See this Question / Answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-email-address - those characters are valid in the local part of the email address.

Comment: Allright, it seam that everything is a legal email adress thise days! thanks for the heads up!

Comment: To validate email address - send mail to this email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `?` and `=` are perfectly valid for an email address. From [Wikipedia on the RFC controlling email addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address)

> The local-part of the email address may use any of these ASCII characters:
>   These special characters: !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~ (ASCII: 33, 35–39, 42, 43, 45, 47, 61, 63, 94–96, 123–126)

If you're trying to make sure the email address actually exists, just be aware that that path is [very difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19262381/2370483)