# how to validate email addreess on CSV file :: laravel

Tags: php, email, csv, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I'm using an csv file to upload students email address to db using laravel.
CSV file contains one column named 'email' to list emails. I want to add a validation to check whther all emails are in correct format or not. 
correct email address format should be @uni.com

please advice

```
    $path = Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath();
                $data = Excel::load($path, function ($reader) {
                })->get();

if (!empty($data) && $data->count() && !empty($data1) && $data1->count() ) {
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                        $insert[] = ['email' => $value->email]; }

 if (!empty($insert)) {
                    DB::table('users')->insert($insert);
                }
```

I'm using laravel maatwebsite/excel plugin

Comment: PHP has `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` filter for that, you can check a list of filters and options at http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php. If the validation is really a big deal you might want to check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19220270/2374643

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use use a Regular Expression check in PHP. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php for reference.

Suppose email addresses can have any character from a to z, the following PHP code will check for correct email format (Generally email addresses have underscores, digits (not as the first character) and so on.. so you need to make a more complex regex to test for it)

```
$pattern = '/[a-z]+@uni\.com/i';

if(preg_match($pattern, $email) == 1) {

    // Correct email address

} else {

    // Incorrect email address

}
```

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to check both conditions for variable $data: "is not empty" and "count greater than 0". Checking either one of them is enough, because if you check the latter condition, at least one result is present in the variable and if you check the former condition (count greater than 0), its the same thing as well.